# R: Need some help on generalized linear mixed models with binomial data

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, binomial-distribution

I would like to find out how the probability of tree-microhabitat occurrence is related to the age of a tree and how is this relationship influenced by KKT and Tree species.
Here is an example of my dataset:

```
aSite          KKT Tree Tspecies Age Concavity Deadwood Epiphyte Exudate
A858500211      SL  407 KU  124 1   0   1   0
A858500211      SL  408 KU  102 1   0   0   0
A858500211      SL  409 KU  96  1   0   0   1
A50574003711    SL  467 KU  39  0   0   1   0
A50574003711    SL  468 KU  45  0   0   0   0
A50574003711    SL  469 KU  34  0   0   0   1
A50574003711    SL  470 HB  39  0   1   1   0
A50574003711    SL  471 HB  38  0   0   0   0
A50574003711    SL  473 HB  43  0   0   1   0
A72467300278    AN  572 HB  26  0   0   0   0
A72467300278    AN  573 HB  25  0   0   0   0
A72467300278    AN  574 KU  23  0   0   0   0
A72467300278    AN  575 KU  74  0   0   0   0
A72467300278    AN  576 KU  19  0   0   0   0
A72467300278    AN  577 HB  25  0   0   0   0
A77170148111    SL  82  HB  52  0   0   1   0
A77170148111    SL  83  HB  64  0   0   1   0
A78237748311    SL  265 KU  74  0   0   0   0
```

As far as I understand (for reading and researching the topic for a week and a half and from my earlier studies), I need to create a generalized linear mixed model for every tree-microhabitat. Since I have about three trees per species in every site, "aSite" should be as a random effect in the model.
And since I have binomial data, I have to use logistic regression (with mixed effects).

So, would this be a correct way to start:

```
model <- glmer(Epiphyte ~ Age + factor(Tspecies) + factor(KKT) + (1|aSite),
               family=binomial,
               data = TabelMHtyypKoigist)
```

I know I have to test the assumptions (I don't know or remember what they are yet) and whether all added factors are relevant or not, but I would appreciate if you would send me the code for plotting the results. I also would appreciate if you'd send me a link for a relevant tutorial-like webpage, from where I could find more help on the topic.

In any case, I tried this:

```
fit <- glmer(Epiphyte ~ Age + factor(Tspecies) + factor(KKT) + (1|aSite),
               family=binomial,
               data = TabelMHtyypKoigist)
predicted = predict(fit, newdata=TabelMHtyypKoigist, type="response")
TabelMHtyypKoigist$Predicted <- predict(fit, TabelMHtyypKoigist, type = "response")
plot(Epiphyte~Age, data=TabelMHtyypKoigist, col="red4")
lines(TabelMHtyypKoigist$Age, TabelMHtyypKoigist$Predicted, col="green4", lwd=2)
```

and got a really weird result.
[image: Here]

What I know is definitely wrong there, is the fact that I need different plots for different Species and for different KKT-s. The points seem accurate but the lines are definitely not the way they supposed to be (I'd like to see one line, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a mixed-effects models in general you would want to specify the fixed- and random-effects structures appropriately. The former concerns the mean of your outcome and the latter the correlation structure. There can be different considerations on how you would go about to build each part, affected by the design of your study and how much information there is in your data.

Typically, you first start with an elaborate specification of the fixed effects, and you focus on selecting the appropriate random-effects structure. There are two schools on how to do this. Either you start with a simple model, e.g., random intercepts, you add in each step more random effects, and you test if you need them, or you start with the most complicated random-effects structure. From personal experience, I most often opt for the former because the latter can result in over-complicated and over-fitted models.

When you have selected the random effects structure, you can return to the fixed effects and interpret the effects you have, and perhaps perform some hypothesis testing. Though, it will not be advisable to simplify the model by excluding non-significant terms.

Now, finally, to investigate how well the model fits your data, and especially for mixed models for non-normally distributed outcomes (i.e., error terms) it would be best to rely on the simulated residuals provided by the [**DHARMa**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html) package.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Earlier, when I tried to do the step-wise-step up procedure, I got an error:
m0.glmer = glmer(Sapwood ~ (1|aSite), data = TabelMHtyypKoigist, family = binomial)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

Comment: It looks like you are trying to predict out of your raw data.frame. You need to create a new data.frame for values you wish to predict. See example in predict.merMod